# threejs loading of gltf results to 404 (Not found) using nodejs express

Tags: express, three.js, webgl, gltf

I know this is common errors but i tried the answers in stackoverflow but it doesnt work.
i am loading a gltf file from this tutorial : https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-load-gltf.html

I am using nodejs express as my server and my directory structure is
[image]

where in public is set as the public folders like this

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

inside the public folder contains the necessary threejs library files and GLTF loader,
so since the public folder is already 'public' and exposed it also contains the assets or the gltf files
[image]

However, when loading the gltf file from this directory, it results to 404.

[image]

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
  
  loader.load('assets/city/scene.gtlf',
     (gltf) => {
        const root = gltf.scene;
        scene.add(root);
     },
     (xhr)=>{

     },
     (error)=>{
       console.log(error);
     });
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: Did you try adding a MIME type for it?  `express.static.mime.define({
  "model/gltf+json": ["gltf"],
  "model/gltf-binary": ["glb"]
 }, true );
`

Comment: yup just added it after your mesage, same thing, error 404